# 3x3 circle icon grid with caption

Tags: html, css

I am looking for ways to add in a 3x3 grid of circle icons to my website. Each icon needs to contain a caption text (including sub-caption text) and be spaced evenly apart. The center icons need to be in the center of the webpage.

I unfortunately have been stuck for the last couple of hours, and I have no idea on how to achieve this. I would appreciate any help.

[image: 3x3 Grid Layout]

Comment: something like this? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PmxoKX

Comment: @MichaelCoker I'd have used `<figure>` + `<figcaption>`. They seem more semantically correct for the case. The classic `<img />` inside `<figure>` could be replaced by `<i class="icon-library-of-choice"></i>`.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu for sure, and would ultimately on their actual content as to what's most semantic. I'm just seeing if this is the general idea for the grid/layout.

Comment: Yeah that is ultimately what I'm going for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a mostly flexbox grid with square cells and centered content that will evenly space the circle/text.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 960px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  background: #eee;
}
.cell {
  flex-basis: 33.3%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
.cell:before {
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  display: block;
  content: '';
}
.circle {
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto 1em;
}
.inner {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="caption">
        <h2>text</h2>
        <h3>sub</h3>
      </div>        
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="caption">
        <h2>text</h2>
        <h3>sub</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="caption">
        <h2>text</h2>
        <h3>sub</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="caption">
        <h2>text</h2>
        <h3>sub</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="caption">
        <h2>text</h2>
        <h3>sub</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="caption">
        <h2>text</h2>
        <h3>sub</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="caption">
        <h2>text</h2>
        <h3>sub</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="caption">
        <h2>text</h2>
        <h3>sub</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="caption">
        <h2>text</h2>
        <h3>sub</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is about what I need. I also would need a sub-caption if possible. Thanks!